# MySQL - DBI: How to tell if the first column is an auto increment column?

Tags: mysql, perl, auto-increment, dbi, dbd-mysql

Is it possible with this information to reliably tell if the first column of the table is an auto increment column?

The available information is as follows :

```
database handle ($dbh)
database name
table name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query [table `COLUMNS` in the mysql information schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.5/en/columns-table.html), using column `EXTRA`.

You would assume that an autoincremented column is of integer datatype, is not nullable and has no default value.

```
my $sql = q{SELECT 1
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
    AND TABLE_NAME = ?
    AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 1
    AND DATA_TYPE = 'int'
    AND COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL
    AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
    AND EXTRA like '%auto_increment%'};

my ($first_col_is_autoincrement) =         
   $dbh->selectrow_array( $sql, undef, $db_name, $table_name );
```

It is also probably possible to use [the DBI catalog functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Catalog-Methods) to achieve the same operation in a database-independent way.

Comment: Also, please add a link to the DBI catalog functions ( https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Catalog-Methods ) - these allow to do the same in a database-independent way )

Comment: @Corion : right... I updated my answer to mention that, although I am unsure if DBI (and/or DBD::mysql) give access to all relevant columns in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Comment: @Corion: Do you know how this (find out if a column is an autoincrement column) is possible with the DBI catalog functions?

Comment: @sid_com as far as I know there is no convenient way to get at the `auto_increment` status of a column. Checking the `extra` field to be `like '%auto_increment%'` is the only way to my knowledge.